# Pi stopped working randomly two nights ago and now won't boot

Tags: boot-issues

[[image: First error booting]][image: Second error booting][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTnkB.jpg)I am not too knowledgeable with this so I will give what information I can.

I use my Pi to run Plex.

2 nights ago my plex stopped working so I went to look at my Pi and now this is what's happening.
I currently have the OS installed on the SD card and 2 external 6GB+8GB drives.

I have tried rebooting. Checking cables. Booting without the HDDs.

I am unsure what the issue is here. Any help would be appreciated!

I have plugged the monitor in to see what is going on and have now received a new response. Photo attached.

Both the red and green leds are solid, no flashing.

I have checked the ethernet and both lights are solid, no flashing. It is no longer showing up in my router with an IP address or under client list. I have tried a different cable, one I know works and still hasn't appeared in my client list.

Comment: Welcome. You need to plug in a monitor to see what is going on.  In the meantime, you should say what the green and red board leds do when you plug the power in.  Please edit those details into the question, do not simply leave them as comments.

Comment: Thanks for responding! I have added photos and edited the post regarding your comment

Comment: Sd card failed read -> sd corrupt.  Re image while preparing to replace.

Comment: Oh dear, so I have to reformat it? I have so much set up on there through docker

Comment: @Abel That is not necessarily the case, although hopefully it is, because it looks like it might be SD card reader failure, which we get here occasionally.  Mel, check and see if both leds do the same thing if you power up with *no* SD card in it.  If so, you could try a fresh card with a new image; you do not have to erase the old one if there's stuff you want on it as it may be easily repaired. WRT the ethernet leds, this is just a hardware state reflecting connectivity. It doesn't mean the OS has initialized it or anything (there obviously is no OS running BTW, that's just firmware output).

Comment: No need to reformat without saving your files first.  Should be able to read files off the card still (easiest with linux) or you might be able to re image it.

Comment: Hi @goldilocks I have powered on the Pi without the SD card reader and am still getting solid green and red LEDs.

Comment: Again, try a different card with a fresh, current image on it.  If that does exactly the same thing, likely the reader is damaged.   If it is something like a loose connection (broken solder), you may be able to notice it with a magnifying glass -- although it probably isn't repairable, this at least would provide confirmation.